How to rewrite commit history from origin master branch
My origin master looks like
A -> B -> C -> D
I want to remove the commits C and D so that my origin master will be like below
A -> B
I have tried do the hard reset and force push as below
git reset --hard HEAD~2 
git push origin HEAD --force

But it is failing to force push in origin master.

Are there any restrictions on the remote repository that's not allowing you to force push the changes? I find your approach is correct but somehow changes are not getting pushed to remote origin

What specifically do you see when it "is failing to force push in origin master"?

Yes, it has restrictions.

Getting this message => remote : error :  GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/master remote: error : At least 2 approving reviews are required by reviewers with write access.! [remote rejected] HEAD -> master ( protected branch hook declined)

So either you need to get 2 reviewers to approve your push, or you need to change the rules.
